# If statement not returning as supposed

Tags: javascript, function

I might seem really dumb but this piece of code is really frustating me.

```
if(fs.exist(parametters[0])){
  fs.remove(parametters[0]);
  return "removed";
}else{
  return "doesn't exist"
}
```

The thing is, the `fs.remove()` is actually called but the function is returning `"doesnt't exist"`, Am I missing something?

I'm not using nodejs, this is from one library i made, is asynchronously.
It's not modifying the parametters but it does change the condition, might be that?

Well I'm posting my `fs` object although I don't think this will change anything.

```
 fs = {
        load: function() {
            if (localStorage[0] == undefined || localStorage[0] == "undefined" || localStorage[0] == "") {
                localStorage[0] = JSON.stringify(fs.files);
            } else {
                fs.files = JSON.parse(localStorage[0]);
            }
        },
        save: function() {
            localStorage[0] = JSON.stringify(fs.files);
        },
        files: [],
        newFile: function(name, content, overwrite) {
            if (overwrite == undefined)
                overwrite = true;
            if (fs.exist(name) && overwrite) {
                fs.find(name).content = content;
                fs.save();
            }
            if (!(fs.exist(name))) {
                fs.files.push({
                    name: name,
                    content: content
                });
                fs.save();
            }
        },
        exist: function(fileName) {
            for (var i = 0; i < fs.files.length; i++) {
                if (fs.files[i].name == fileName)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        find: function(fileName) {
            for (var i = 0; i < fs.files.length; i++) {
                if (fs.files[i].name == fileName)
                    return fs.files[i];
            }
            return false;
        },
        format: function() {
            fs.files = [];
            localStorage[0] = undefined;
        },
        write: function(name, content, overwrite) {
            if (overwrite == undefined)
                overwrite = true;
            if (fs.exist(name) && overwrite) {
                fs.find(name).content = content;
                fs.save();
            }
            if (!(fs.exist(name))) {
                fs.files.push({
                    name: name,
                    content: content
                });
                fs.save();
            }
        },
        remove: function(file) {
            var arrToreturn = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < fs.files.length; i++) {
                if (fs.files[i].name != file)
                    arrToreturn.push(fs.files[i]);
            }
            fs.files = arrToreturn;
            fs.save();
            return arrToreturn;
        }
    }
```

Resolved - 
After a few days of inspecting the code I found the bug where the function was called twice, the amount of code was really huge so it took me a while.

Comment: Does `fs.exist()` do any changes on its parameters? Otherwise like Jarmanda says, I don't see how this is happening. You may have a race condition elsewhere.

Comment: Node's standard `fs` functions are asynchronous. The documentation goes to great lengths explaining this, I recommend you start with reading the documentation before you start wondering why your code does not work.

Comment: I'd put console.log's everywhere (well, there's really only four places to do so) to see what is up with that

Comment: @Tomalak - regardless of sync/async, you don't expect both branches of if/else to be executed in normal everyday program flow

Comment: Can you show the entire function and all the places where you are calling this function?

Comment: can you show where fs is created/added to?

Comment: @Tomalak brings up a very good point. `fs.exist` expects a callback, and it's there that you would perform your logic.

Comment: @DaveChen It does not execute both branches of the code. If we are talking about Node here, `fs.exists` does not return if a file exists.

Comment: As I said, I'm not using Nodejs, and my  fs.exist() will always return true or false @Tomalak this problem has no sense I will try rewrite all the functions associated to this tho

Comment: @LouisCastro I suspected something like that (you should have said that from the start). How on earth are we supposed to know what's wrong with code that *you wrote* but you don't show? And what are you using, if not node (given the fact that normal JavaScript does not have access to the file system)?

Comment: In any case, there is absolutely no way that JavaScript executes both branches of an `if` statement. Your error analysis is wrong, clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a semi-colon to `return "doesn't exist"`, it should read `return "doesn't exist";`

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Object, still it works.

We can assume this to be an File object ARRAY, indexOf still works to find if the item exists.

Please have a look upon below example:

var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");

Result is 2 in case Apple is found
Result is -1 in case Apple is not found

You can have some more options at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try javascript indexOf function to check if the value really exists, BEFORE REMOVE Operation.

Example below:

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

=> Gives 13 if found
   if we search for "welcome1" -> will give -1

Comment: I doubt "fs" is a string. It could be, but I don't see why you'd make that assumption. I think it's more likely that it's a filesystem object and that he's deleting a file, based on the variable name.

Answer (score -1):

Use This Code For Solving This Problam. thanks

var fs = require('fs-extra')

fs.remove('/tmp/myfile', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

console.log('success!')
})

fs.removeSync('/home/jprichardson') //I just deleted my entire HOME directory.